# SQL: Increment a row when value in another row changes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
Sequence   Change
 100         0
 101         0
 103         0
 106         0
 107         1
 110         0
 112         1
 114         0
 115         0
 121         0
 126         1
 127         0
 134         0
```

I need an additional column, `Group`, whose values increment based on the occurrence of 1 in `Change`. How is that done? I'm using Microsoft Server 2012.

```
Sequence   Change    Group
 100         0         0
 101         0         0
 103         0         0
 106         0         0
 107         1         1
 110         0         1
 112         1         2
 114         0         2
 115         0         2
 121         0         2
 126         1         3
 127         0         3
 134         0         3
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I have no idea why this question receives downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*, sum(change) over (order by sequence) as grp
from t;
```